# Set color of an image

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making simple notebook app. I want for each note set `image` like star or bell and set its color. What is the way to "change" color of image in `WPF`. **I will be satisfied with some effect that will only show the color in the app. I don't need to change the picture.** Is possible to use some colored `mask` on the surface of the image?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szEbO.png)

Comment: Could you provide an example of your code and what type of images are you speaking about. Are you working with **Bitmap** images for example?
You could use [Shape objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview) to draw a shape to the screen. So, you could change the color easily.

Comment: @SebastianInones I want to set color and then show colored image in my app. I use png. I dont want overwrite image. I want only use something like mask on the image if is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said about : *use some colored mask on the surface of the image?*

I guess you could you use [Opacity Masks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/opacity-masks-overview).
Also, take a look at this which is solved [using a named-color as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114651/specify-transparency-level-of-a-named-color-in-xaml)

Another approach based on what you said : *I will be satisfied with some effect that will only show the color in the app*
you could use some [Bitmap Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/bitmap-effects-overview), maybe the [OuterGlowBitmapEffect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.effects.outerglowbitmapeffect?view=netframework-4.8)

I hope this points you in the right direction.