# How to multiply a DynamicResource with a constant?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, converters, multibinding

The `TextBlock.FontSize` must be the product of

- a dynamic resource `FontSizeFactor`
- a static hard-coded value `32`

How can I do this in XAML?

(With Binding, MultiBinding, Converter or whatever, but without code behind)

Comment: Is DynamicRsource is mandatory for you??  or static resource is also acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Math Converter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239251/MathConverter-How-to-Do-Math-in-XAML) You can do a lot of calculations in xaml by using this ValueConverter

Comment: I fear it doesn't work, as you cannot set a dynamic resource to a Binding Source

Comment: Sorry didnt think about that. But you can write a markup extension. Please see this question that was asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805351/use-ivalueconverter-with-dynamicresource

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805351/use-ivalueconverter-with-dynamicresource doesn't work at all... I spent an additional hour to test and understand what's going wrong, but the solution provided is simply wrong (see the comment I added to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the below solution meets your requirement. Note: The solution works for staticResource. Inside the convertor you can product the FontSizeFactor value and 32

```
<Window.Resources>
     <Clr:String x:Key="FontSizeFactor">2</Clr:String>
     <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
   <Canvas>
       <TextBlock Text="siva" FontSize="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, 
                                    ConverterParameter={StaticResource FontSizeFactor}}" />
   </Canvas>
```

Comment: It doesn't work: DynamicResource cannot be set to ConverterParameter

Comment: ok, I will post another solution. before I Just want to make sure that, you want to bind the DynamicResource only one time right?? What i assume is you dont want to update the TextBlock's font size when the dynamic Resource value is changed. Correct me if I am wrong.