# How to bind with dynamic resource and send it into my converter

Tags: wpf, converters

So i have this:

```
<system:Int32 x:Key="ListViewPacketManipulationOptionsComboBoxSelectedIndex">0</system:Int32>
```

And when This `Value` is `> 0` i want my `TextBox` `IsEnables=True` :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return (int)value > 0;
}
```

My `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbHeaderOriginValue"   
         IsEnabled="{DynamicResource ListViewPacketManipulationOptionsComboBoxSelectedIndex}"/>
```

Currently I did not find any way to add my `Converter`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use IValueConverter with DynamicResource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805351/use-ivalueconverter-with-dynamicresource)

Comment: @Jack, DynamicResource is more complex than StaticResource and can't be used as Source directly

Comment: So whats the solution ?

Comment: @user2908206, did you read duplicates?

Comment: I can see several answers inside your link, which one ?

Comment: The one with the most votes.

Comment: If the int is "dynamic", why don't you simply bind to a property that returns the int value?